# How to allow IP address through iptables ... NOW as opposed to the last few years

Tags: iptables

As in the post (the first on DuckDuckGo) [How to allow all connections from specific IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/857190/how-to-allow-all-connections-from-specific-ip-address) ... I am having a similiar problem but the opposite.  I have used a basic iptables files for years that has always worked and never been a problem, which I originally got from an old Debian doc and used everywhere ... even on Debian 10 (which is what I'm using.). It was just an iptables shell script, but when it refused to allow my IP (which was the whole point) I tried netfilter-persistent and got the exact same results.  My rules match that of those in the "OP's" post but it is blocking me for some reason.

Here is the rules.v4 file:

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Aug 16 06:38:44 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [5:212]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [144:19527]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s my.ip.add.res/32 -j ACCEPT
```

That's pretty much it, except now instead of YEARS of it working perfectly, something changed and it blocks me instead.  (I have verified my outgoing IP just to be sure.).

Comment: Test whether it is due to iptables or something else by temporarily disabling iptables and seeing if you can connect.

Comment: I disabled it but before that and after I have a new problem ... after just sitting idle for a few hours it's blocking me now, even though I show up clearly in iptables -L list.  I've wiped and re-started this VPS several times and yet this firewall will not cooperate.

Comment: I forgot to mention that for a moment it did let me in before (and anybody) with nothing changing I'm aware of.

Comment: Has your IP address changed?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I really made a silly mistake.  Instead of typing my IP address like I have countless times, I decided to throw a '1' in front of one of the quads.  Obviously this caused it to reject entry.  Sorry for the waste of time!